# sorting names in java using comparable interface

Tags: java

what is the use of equals,hashcode,toString methods in this below example?
  Can anyone  please explain me in simple way with example for the same

```
import java.util.*;
//sort lists of comparable elements 
public class Name implements Comparable<Name> {
    private final String firstName, lastName;

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        if (firstName == null || lastName == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String firstName() { return firstName; }
    public String lastName()  { return lastName;  }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Name))
            return false;
        Name n = (Name) o;
        return n.firstName.equals(firstName) && n.lastName.equals(lastName);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 31*firstName.hashCode() + lastName.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public int compareTo(Name n) {
        int lastCmp = lastName.compareTo(n.lastName);
        return (lastCmp != 0 ? lastCmp : firstName.compareTo(n.firstName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the top code not working?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin  No its working.. i have mention my question to explain these logics happening in this program to help newbie to understand this concept.  its from Oracle http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: -1 `please anyone help me.. waiting..` don't be so impatient, yo9u only asked the question a couple of minutes ago. `i tried to understand this exmple but could not` - what don't you understand about it? Any code I post would be the same. It looks straight forward and simple to me. If you really want an answer then spend more time with a proper question. We can't read you mind. We don't know what you find confusing.

Comment: @camickr what this above program is doing?

Comment: It isn't doing anything. It isn't a program, just a class.

Comment: I suggest you try running it by adding a main seeing what it does with different values.  You can use your debugger to help you. Or you could give us why you think the method works and explain clearer what you don't understand.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes thanks for idea! At least one person i found here who is helpful saying exactly what should i do. Thanks Mr.Peter

Comment: Reading one line at a time. It compares the last name, and it's same it compare the first name.  The comparison return -1 or less than, +1 for greater than and 0 for equal.

Comment: @beginner, `At least one person i found here who is helpful saying exactly what should i do` - excuse me I asked you what you found confusing and you have not replied. Also, you still haven't replied to Peter's comment, so you haven't done anything to follow his suggestion. If you don't make an effort then why should we?

Comment: @camickr  i still   trying to understand after  reading above all comments & below answer to make out. In my contry its 4am, i have not slept & trying to understand my above question

Comment: Your interviewer is just going to love you...

Comment: @PeterLawrey i have updated my question with codes & comment within it.. try to make it simple with explanation.. thanks for your timing.

Comment: toString/equals/hashCode and getters like firstName and lastName are normal Java class concepts but not related to the concept of a comparable object.

Comment: @eckes i have updated my question. It was long back i asked this question when i was fresher in java -thanks

Comment: @camickr Hi i have updated my question, can you please vote it up if you like. I asked it long back ago, now i am trying to correct it the way how i asked. _thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public String firstName() { return firstName; } //what is the use of this line

It's called a getter. It allows you to get the value while hiding the implementation from the calling code.

> Name n = (Name) o;  // why casting in n Name obj & also i did see anywhere call of this method

equals(Object) takes any object, however we need to see it as a `Name` so we can access it's fields/methods.

> return 31*firstName.hashCode() + lastName.hashCode(); //what is this? i mean 31* , this line?

`31` is a common prime number used in hash codes.  By multiply the hashCode of one field by a number it means that if you swap the names around the hashCode won't be the same.

> public String toString() {  //why this method is written, it is not called from aney where

Does it have to be?  It might be called implicitly like

```
System.out.println(name); // calls toString()
```

> public int compareTo(Name n) {  //this method also not called from anywhere

Perhaps it is not used.  A common pattern for developers to implement methods which might be used but never are.  Another approach is to follow YAGNI (You Aint Gonna Need It) and only implement method you know you need, not ones you can imagine.

For example, you might find that you need a comparator which sorts by first name, then last.  Now you can't just make the class Comparable because it already is.  You mgith change the compareTo but this might break some thing.  If it is used, this is fairly easy to find and so you know you can't change it.  However, it's harder to find something which is not there. i.e. proving it is never used and thus you can just change the method is harder.

It would have been much easier if methods not used were not added, then you know they are not used. ;)

Comment: After debugging, i understood this concept nicely  but still it apply this YAGNI rule to the this "hash-code" & "equal" methods. my debugger did not went to these two methods. why?  i think because these 2methods are not need in my sorting case.  But in which condition these  two methods can also be called by my debugger?

Comment: @beginner They will be called when you call them, or call something which calls them. A common example would be to add multiple `Name` to a `HashSet`

Comment: `"hash-code" & "equal" methods. my debugger did not went to these two methods. why?` Read the `Object API`.  Classes should generally override these methods from the default implementation in the Object class.

Comment: @camickr if they are used.  If not, perhaps they shouldn't be. I think the OP doesn't understand why they were not called.

Comment: Thanks Peter, i asked this question long ago . Now i am master in this coding... i implemented this in many Project modules :)

Answer (score 2):

```
what this above program is doing?
```

It is a class that implements `Comparable` that will be used to sort your last name in ascending order with overridden equals, hashCode and toString method.

```
public int compareTo(Name n) {
    int lastCmp = lastName.compareTo(n.lastName);
    return (lastCmp != 0 ? lastCmp : firstName.compareTo(n.firstName));
}
```

For sorting the string the `first line` is to check if the value is greater or less than the compared string.

The `second line` is when the both `last name` are equal then it will sort the `first name` instead.

**sample** String

```
banana rod 
ras app 
apple rod
```

it will be sorted as

```
ras app 
apple rod 
banana rod
```

For the overriden `toString()`

When you print an Object of the name without overriding the `toString`

**sample**

```
 Name na = new Name();
 System.out.println(na);
```

It will print the memory location of that object in memory

and since it is overridden it it will print the `first and last name`.

For the overriden `hashCode()`

If you are trying to compare two Name object `hashcode` with the same last and first name they will return true.

**sample:**

```
 Name na = new Name();
 Name na2 = new Name();

 System.out.println(na.hashCode() == na2.hashCode()); //will return true if first and last name are the same
```

Comment: @beginner if you trying to compare the Name objects. let say if both object have the same first and last name and it will return true

Comment: i have updated my question with codes & comment within it.. try to make it simple with explanation.. thanks for your timing.

Comment: but this returned `false` the last sample of your for hashcode..  i run this `Name na = new Name("a","a");
   Name na2 = new Name("a","a");
  System.out.println(na.hashCode() == na2.hashCode());`